# Log4j configure and watch not working properly

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j for loggin purpose in my application. Since now to configure the logging i was using the following code :

```
LogManager.resetConfiguration();
InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties"); 
Properties props= new Properties();
props.load(stream);
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

But the problem with this was , that whenever i wanted to change the logging level during the process, i had to restart the server. So i changed the code to :-

```
LogManager.resetConfiguration();
PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(("log4j.properties", 900000L);
```

this code ideally should help to re-load the log4j.properties file after the time specified, which i have mentioned as 15 minutes. But still the code is not working

Am i missing somthing during the code?

Regards.

Comment: Have you created a standalone example of this and tried that to see if it works as you expect? Also, have you moved from a classpath-loading technique to a filesystem-based technique? In which case, make sure your path to log4j.properties is correct.

Comment: You have an extra opening bracket before the filename... PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(("log4j.properties", 900000L);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`configureAndWatch()` watches files. Not resources in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution and works fine! The point is that your must provide the path like a file not like a resource.

```
//Resource
DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch("/log4j.xml", 2000L);

//File
DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch("./src/log4j.xml", 2000L);
```

Try the second option and modify the *log4j.xml* and test it!