# Change level at runtime ( through log4j.properties and through code)

Tags: java, log4j

I have heard that we can change the log4j properties at runtime but i need help in clarifing the same.

I know that through code we can change the log4j properties at runtime. If i have made changes in `log4j.properties` file then also the changed properties will be reflected or not. Is there anything which read the properties file at runtim e and apply the changes if it finds the properties modified?

Comment: Please give people credit for their effort to help you and [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/164138) on your previous questions. You haven't accepted a single answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the level simply at runtime :

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("insert name of logger here" );
logger.setLevel(Level.TRACE);
```

Otherwise you can do the changes in the configuration file and then reload it :

```
      LogManager.resetConfiguration();
      PropertyConfigurator.configure(propertyfile);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer....

Is there any way to know that my log4j.xml has been modified and now i have to reset the conf and reload it.

Actually i have log4j.xml on my server (internal).Users deploy the applications on it.Now at that time they modify the log4j.xml like adding loggers etc.To see the changes they need to restart the server.....server and application..they are two different entity...

Comment: if application user modify the log4j.xml then 1st option is they need to restart the server to get those changes 2nd option is..i change my server code and  somehow got to know that my log4j.xml has been modified and now i have to reload it.

I hope you got my point.Looking for the answer.

Comment: You could use the 'configureAndWatch' (see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#configureAndWatch(java.lang.String%2C%20long) ) as it will check on regular intervals wheter the logging configuration has changed.

Comment: Some application servers offer dynamic logging configuration reloading out of the box. I yours doesn't create a web app add a ServletContextListener to it. Then reset logging configuration using the code snippet in the answer above, but call configureAndWatch on PropertyConfiguratior instead of simply configure.

Comment: @Zapodot : could you please explain this line "I yours doesn't create a web app add a ServletContextListener to it." I have read on net that Log4J comes with a “configureAndWatch” facility. In this scenario a thread with a configurable delay runs and checks if the configuration file for changes since last load and reloads if necessary.`Again this is not an option when you have deployed web applications as WAR`.[http://www.objectsource.com/j2eechapters/Ch06-Logging_Service.htm] Enter JMX. does this means that configureAndWatch method does not work on web applications.

Comment: @Zapodot : I have tried to use configureAndWatch method but its not working.please see this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468882/log4j-configure-and-watch-not-working-properly/8725927#8725927](stackoverflow link)...i dont understand the line `configureAndWatch() watches files. Not resources in the classpath`...could you please explain it to me.

Comment: I guess that means you can not use configureAndWatch for log configurations that are loaded by using the classloader .getResource or .getResourcesAsStream properties which i guess will be the case in most app-servers. However you may use it to load logging config using a physical path such as /etc/myapp/log4j.xml or c:\myfiles\log4j.xml